# Custom Routing in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, url-routing

I'm having some issues with custom routing. What I'm looking to do is remove the model from the route and dynamically use the record name.

so instead of:

```
site.com/events/my-event
```

I would like it to be:

```
site.com/my-event
```

I hacked this to work with the below code, only issue is I can't access my admin namespace as it's being treated as an event record (and any other route):

```
  get('/:id', to: redirect do |params, request|
   id = request.path.gsub("/", "")
   "/events/#{id}"
  end)
```

I know this redirect is not right, I'm just not well versed in routing options. How should this be done properly?

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :events, param: :id, path: "" do
    get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: :login
    get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: :logout
    post 'sessions', to: 'sessions#create', as: :session_create
  end

  namespace 'admin' do
    root "events#index"

    resources :sessions, only: [:create]
    get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: :login
    get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: :logout

    resources :events
  end

end
```

Comment: Could you please post the whole `routes.rb` file?

Comment: Make sure any two routes should not be same. If you are specific to this then change the admin routes with some prefix.

Answer (score 1):

(1) To fix `/admin` to go to the right path, move the `namespace` line **above** the events resources so that it is matched first:

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified [2.2 CRUD, Verbs, and Actions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

```
# routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  root "events#index"
  #...
  resources :events
end

resources :events, param: :name, path: ""
```

Use `:param` and `:path` to match for `site.com/myevent` instead of `site.com/events/:id`

Your `events` controller:

```
# events_controller.rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  # ... 

 private

   def set_event
     @event = Event.find_by(name: params[:name])
   end
end
```

Your `admin events` controller:

```
# admin/events_controller.rb
class Admin::EventsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  private     
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find params[:id]
    end
end
```

TIP: To get a complete list of the available routes use `rails routes` in your terminal [5.1 Listing Existing Routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes)

Comment: thanks @s3tjan this is close. So I am using a slug with friendly_id. I'm still having issues accessing the admin. It's directing the admin path (my.site.com/admin) to the set_event method in the events_controller. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please post your `routes.rb` file, I think could be related with the `:namespace`

Comment: You should use a constraint. See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. Could you give me an example of how you would use constraints to allow `/admin` to go to the the right path?

Comment: @JollyGreenGiant I updated my answer, try it. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Rails lets you specify what a routing URL should look like:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths

Comment: this is not helpful, If I had an understanding of how it worked I would just refer to the docs myself. I'm looking for some actual code example guidance. As I stated, routing is just not something I'm grasping after unsuccessfully attempting to do this with the information I have found myself

Comment: Per the docs, if you don't want your controller (or anything else) included in your URL, you can omit from your path by doing: `path: ''`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need redirect.
You need to match all requests to one controller/action.

```
get '/(*all)', to: 'home#app'
```

Inside this action check what is coming in params and render appropriate view.

PS: it will capture all requests, even for not found images, js, etc.

Comment: but how can I still access the admin? That's my biggest issue is that `/admin` is being picked up as an potential event id

Comment: put what I mentioned in the last line. before you can put other routes. So it will like a default route.

Comment: get '/account', to: 'account#index'
...
get '/(*all)', to: 'home#app'